# Flutter vscode error when run project Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: flutter, exception, visual-studio-code

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-rc01.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\username.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\867ebb0c25fd418a6c5a03d6fe3190ae\work-runtime-2.7.0-rc01\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 50s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1